# Can not retrieve google translation

Tags: google-translate

I'm new to Google Translate API and i tried to get translated my words using the below URL and it says.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

I used the below URL.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=My_Key&source=en&target=sw&    
q=Hello%20world
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have enough reputation to give you a comment , I will give it as answer.

You can do only Limited number of translations per day because of free subscription. To have unlimited you must buy it for $1 AFAIK. you have to register and then have to buy.Then you can do unlimited translations.

From Google:

Usage fees:

- Translation:

> $20 per 1 M characters of text, where the charges are adjusted in
>   proportion to the number of characters actually provided. For example,
>   if you were to translate 500K characters, you would be billed $10.

- Language Detection:

> $20 per 1 M characters of text, where the charges are adjusted in
>   proportion to the number of characters actually provided.

- Usage limits:

> Google Translate API has a default limit of 2 M chars/day. You can
>   increase this limit up to 50 M chars/day in the Cloud Console by
>   following the instructions below. If you need to translate more than
>   50 M chars/day.

For more information : https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing

Comment: i used a paid Google Account API key. But this is the result.